# ¿Porque obtengo es error con glassfish y netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, web, jsp, glassfish

[image: Obtengo este error al enviar el formulario]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y realmente no se eu esta mal. Este es el codigo:
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Todo supply a tittle</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name= "frmDatos" action="pagina1.jsp" method="get">
        <b>Formulario</b>
        <br>
        Nombre:<input type="text" name="txtNombre" value="" />
        <br>
        Apellido:<input type="text" name="txtApellido" value="" />
           <br>
        Numero:<input type="text" name="Numeor" value="" />
        <br>
        <input type="submit"  value="mostrar" name="btnMostrar" />
    </form>        
    </body>
</html>


**pagina1.jsp**

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<% 
    String nombre  = request.getParameter("txtNombre");
    String apellido  = request.getParameter("txtApellido");
    int n = Integer .parseInt(request.getParameter("txtNumero"));
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Datos Pagina</h1>
        <br>
        Nombre:<%=nombre%>
        <br>
        Apellido:<%=apellido%>
        <br>
        Listado de numeros:
        <%for (int x = 1; x < n; x++) {%>
        <br>
        Numero= <%=x%>
        <br>
        <%}%>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: YA cambie la ubicación del .jsp ajora esta asi]

Pero ahora obtengo este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el jsp está dentro del index.html? Si no es así, por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/190014/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: No no estaba amigo, pero ya lo puse dentro del index, solo que ahora optengo error 500

Comment: nononono, la idea es que estén separados, amigo. El `action` del formulario te redirige al jsp con un HTTP POST, sino que en tu pregunta están los dos códigos en un solo bloque de código y no se entiende cómo están los archivos. Para que haya un servlet atendiendo las peticiones a tus jsp, el web.xml debe tener un servlet-mapping... pon tu web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás enviando mal el nombre de un parámetro.
En la url tienes puesto `Numeor=2`, pero en el html tienes `request.getParameter("txtNumero")`.

De esta manera, al llegar `null` te da el error que pones.

Corrige la url de forma que ponga `txtNumero=2` y solucionado.

Comment: Osea aquí `Numero:<input type="text" name="Numeor" value="" />` y a la hora de recoger el parámetro aquí `int n = Integer .parseInt(request.getParameter("txtNumero"));` Cambia por el ejemplo el name a `name="txtNumero"`